# Почему запрос к БД не выдает нужный результат?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Здравствуйте. Имеется маленькая БД с записями
[image: БД]

я хочу получать значения колонок COL_1 и COL_2 если в каком то из них что то записано

написал вот  такой запрос для этого

```
    public Cursor get_data()
{
    return refillDB.query(DB_TABLE,
            new String[] {COL_1, COL_2, COL_SORT},
            COL_1 + " NOT LIKE ?" + " OR " + COL_2 + " NOT LIKE ?",
            new String[] {"null"},
            null, null,
            COL_SORT + " ASC");
}
```

согласно нему я должен получить строки с `id` 1 и 2, но я получаю только строку с `id 1`. Tсли я поменяю в условии запроса

```
COL_1 + " NOT LIKE ?" + " OR " + COL_2 + " NOT LIKE ?",
```

на

```
COL_2 + " NOT LIKE ?" + " OR " + COL_1 + " NOT LIKE ?",
```

то вернется строка с `id 2`
почему не возвращаются обе строки? ведь условие OR должно  выдать все строки где либо `COL_1` не `null` либо `COL_2` не `null` ?

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо!! оформите пожалуйста как ответ, что бы я мог принять его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно указать и второй аргумент:

```
new String[] {"null", "null"}
```

К каждому новому вопросу в условии `COL_1 + " NOT LIKE ?" + " OR " + COL_2 + " NOT LIKE ?"` берется следующий из списка параметр, у вас есть параметр только для первого вопроса.